# How do I feed a FFT data as input to a CNN/DNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

[image: Sample FFT Data]

As shown in the picture, I have some samples of FFT data, out of which some are from the system which are working good, and some from systems which has faults.

I tried calculating PeakValue, RMS and tried to train the network using DNN as well as Linear methods, but in vain.

My question is, Do we have any mechanishm so that we can feed the raw data (without pre processing) and train the system, if not, what pre-processing steps should be taken care and what model of neural network should I deploy ?

Comment: 1. Feature extraction in frequency domain has been widely studied in Signal Processing community. The point is that usually the nature of your data is crucial here. Frequency features extracted from an image are different than an acoustic signal. In acoustic signals, speech has different properties from music and so on and so forth. So better go through the literature and also explain more about your data here.
 2. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546643) is a pretty good starting point for your problem. Have a look.

Comment: 3. The last but not the least is not to get stuck in the trend of NNs. I used to do signal processing long time before this hype of NNs and I would say if the signals are not that complicated you over-estimate your problem by using NNs. The whole point is to find good features inside the data. If you have access to original signals you may also try time-frequency analysis using e.g. wavelets